# Не удаляется иконка с рабочего стола

Tags: c#, icon

Создал программку на C#, упаковал её с помощью Visual Studio Installer (Setup Wizard), указал в настройках, что нужно создать иконку на рабочем столе. После установки на Win10 (на других не проверял), иконка на отрез не хочет удаляться. Что это может быть? На всякий случай сделал скрин вкладки подробней этой иконки. Кстати, что интересно, на рабочем столе я вижу иконку, а если зайти в эту папку с помощью проводника, то его там нет... как такое может быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Она в `Public`, а не у пользователя.

Comment: большое спасибо, чёт заработался, целый час провозился из-за своей невнимательности(( иконка не удалялась из общего рабочего стола из-за того что не было прав